# SQL Pivot for multiple columns in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My table structure like

```
----------------------------------------------
AccountNo | Ben1 | Ben2 | Ben3 | Ben4 | Type |
----------------------------------------------
A1234     | xyz1 | xyz2 | xyz3 | xyz4 | P    |
A1005     | pqr1 | pqr2 | pqr3 | pqr4 | C    |
----------------------------------------------
```

I need to pivot above table to

```
-------------------------
AccountNo | Name | Type |
-------------------------
A1234     |xyz1  |  P   |
A1234     |xyz2  |  P   |
A1234     |xyz3  |  P   |
A1234     |xyz4  |  P   |
A1005     |pqr1  |  C   |
A1005     |pqr2  |  C   |
A1005     |pqr3  |  C   |
A1005     |pqr4  |  C   |
-------------------------
```

By an sql query how I pivot to get above result

Comment: have you tried searching, it's a pretty common question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+pivot+columns+rows

Comment: Also I have a Ben1Type, Ben2Type, Ben3Type and Ben4TYpe cols correspondingly.

Comment: I got answer form the url : http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.in/2009/04/unpivot-multiple-columns.html

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT AccountNo, Name, Type
FROM
(
    SELECT AccountNo, Ben1, Ben2, Ben3, Ben4, Type
    FROM yourTable
) AS t1
UNPIVOT 
(
    Name FOR Names IN (Ben1, Ben2, Ben3, Ben4)
) AS t2
```

[SQL Server UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

**Update:**

You can't directly unpivot `NULL` values, because these records will be removed from the result set.  One option would be to replace the `NULL` `VARCHAR` columns with the text `'NULL'`.  This would at least let you retain all the original information while also being able to see what was originally `NULL`.

```
SELECT AccountNo, Name, Type
FROM
(
    SELECT AccountNo,
           COALESCE(Ben1, 'NULL'),
           COALESCE(Ben2, 'NULL'),
           COALESCE(Ben3, 'NULL'),
           COALESCE(Ben4, 'NULL'),
           Type
    FROM yourTable
) AS t1
UNPIVOT 
(
    Name FOR Names IN (Ben1, Ben2, Ben3, Ben4)
) AS t2
```

Comment: Sometimes Ben2,Ben3,Ben4 will be null.

Comment: Also I have a Ben1Type, Ben2Type, Ben3Type and Ben4TYpe cols correspondingly.

Comment: @ellickakudyrajeesh I have updated my answer with one possible workaround (though there are many).

Comment: Thank you Tim. 

Also I got the right answer that I looking for from the url : http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.in/2009/04/unpivot-multiple-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using **UNPIVOT**

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTb(AccountNo VARCHAR(5),Ben1 VARCHAR(5), Ben2 VARCHAR(5), Ben3 VARCHAR(5), Ben4 VARCHAR(5), Type CHAR(1));

INSERT INTO #TestTb(AccountNo,Ben1,Ben2,Ben3,Ben4,Type)
VALUES ('A1234','xyz1','xyz2','xyz3','xyz4','P'),
    ('A1005','pqr1','pqr2','pqr3','pqr4','C');

SELECT  AccountNo,
        Name,
        Type
FROM (
        SELECT AccountNo,Ben1,Ben2,Ben3,Ben4,Type
        FROM #TestTb
    ) AS Src
    UNPIVOT (
        Name FOR AccName IN(Ben1,Ben2,Ben3,Ben4)
    ) AS UNPVT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use UNION ALL

```
SELECT AccountNo, Ben1 as Name, [Type]
FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT AccountNo, Ben2, [Type]
FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT AccountNo, Ben3, [Type]
FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT AccountNo, Ben4, [Type]
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY AccountNo, Name
```

Output:

```
AccountNo   Name    Type
A1005       pqr1    C
A1005       pqr2    C
A1005       pqr3    C
A1005       pqr4    C
A1234       xyz1    P
A1234       xyz2    P
A1234       xyz3    P
A1234       xyz4    P
```